# parse.com: Cache results as a json file

Tags: parse-platform

For my app I have a long running task that generates stats. I would like the stats to be available to my users as a json file. Is there a way using parse to store the results of the task as a json that my users can retrieve? It would be great if there was some server side caching that I could take advantage of as well.

**UPDATE**

The following code takes my array of dictionaries and saves it as a file. I am now trying to store the file as part of a table called Cache. However the result is

```
Input: {}
Result: undefined
```

The code snippet looks like

```
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
...


var json = <array of dictionaries>;
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(json);
var buf = new Buffer(jsonStr, 'utf8');

var json64 = buf.toString('base64');

var parseFile = new Parse.File('result', { "base64" : json64 }, 'application/json');
parseFile.save().then(function(parseFile) {
    // The file has been saved to Parse.
    var cache = new Cache();
    attr = {};
    attr['file'] = parseFile;
    console.log(parseFile.url());
    cache.save(attr, {
        success : function(result) {
            status.success("Cached");
        },
        error : function(result, error) {
            status.error("Error: + " + error.message);
        }
    });
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    status.error(error.message);
});
```

Comment: Does your `Cache` class have a column called `file` of type `File`?

Comment: yes it has column called file of type File

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can you provide more information about the result you're getting?